# Google hasn't spotted my AMP pages, and I'm not sure why

Tags: amp-html

I've followed the specification, I thought.

There's a link href rel=amphtml in [this page](https://media.info/radio/opinion/finland-a-radio-app-that-does-more-than-youd-expect-2) that points to the [AMP version](https://media.info/radio/opinion/finland-a-radio-app-that-does-more-than-youd-expect-2/amp), yet three days after implementing it, submitting both pages to Google, and waiting, Webmaster Tools still tells me I have no AMP pages and the AMP pages don't exist on a Google search.

What's up?

Comment: As an aside: it's now found just one page (there are plenty more), though that has kicked up some errors in the Schema.org implementation, which are now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Mueller points out here: https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/bwnHgShgDm7 it takes about a week for the Search Console's report to update.

You can see that your page is in the Google AMP Cache by looking at: https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/media.info/radio/opinion/finland-a-radio-app-that-does-more-than-youd-expect-2/amp

Comment: Developers in Australia might also note that AMP hasn't been launched here, due to local publishers not adopting it.

Answer (score -1):

- Its need time before google add new pages in the console. Maybe 3 days to short.

  - upload a sitemap in the console
  - and your AMP site are not valid. It missing the AMP script for adsense ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting point about Adsense, I'll explore that. It doesn't show me any validation errors.

A sitemap already exists for the canonical pages, and they're in the Google search.

Comment: "your AMP site are not valid. It missing the AMP script for adsense ;-)" - as far as I can see, it is valid, and there is no additional module required to display AdSense. (And the AdSense ads work, too). Could you explain a little more?

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I was thought at analytics not adsense, sorry.